# Using Firebase with Unity and WebGL

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, firebase-remote-config

I was thinking of using Firebase remote config with my Unity based game.

I intent to release the game on Facebook with WebGL, and was wondering if there is Firebase implementation for WebGL as part of the SDK?

Answer (score 3):

No, but according to [Stewart Miles](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/hoXG6F4QPiI) from Google, to do this we should

> taking our C# interface and using the [Firebase JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) from C# when
> building for the web rather than using the REST API or any Unity SDKs
> that call our public REST APIs directly

You can read more here on how to [call JavaScript functions from Unity scripts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) or read more about it in [Patrick Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58175953/5675325).

Answer (score 2):

Firebase-Unity SDK is only for [IOS and Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) Platforms. However you can [implement plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) to use [web API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for your WebGL build.

If you would release your game on Facebook platform its better to use [Parse.com](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/unity/guide/). However WebGL is not supported in main SDK because its multi-threaded structure but an [alternative version](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/parse-developers/h4LEhab4RTY/dPUsODxMBgAJ) is available which works with WebGL.

Comment: Well, Parse is R.I.P for some time now, and it seems that RemoteConfig is not supported for web so using JavaScript to access the API is not possible...

Comment: Actually, firebase works with the windows platform as well

Comment: @LasithaLakmal this answer is more than 4 years old, can you please update it with the relevant resources