# How can I buil my game with the error message "Cannot build player while editor is importing assets or compiling scripts"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I cannot build my game. I"m getting the message "Cannot build player while editor is importing assets or compiling scripts". I need to build my game until tomorrow. I also have many errors in console. I tried to delete use Unity Editor in every script, but that did not help. [image]

Comment: What do you not understand in the error message? What are the compiler errors? They should appear above in the console ....

Comment: I have edited my post, you can now see my errors, it's one script, which gives me the errors.

Comment: well .. would you mind showing the script? Though the error is quite self-explanatory, isn't it? Is Firebase imported and compatible with your build target?

Comment: This question is thereby probably a duplicate of [Using Firebase with Unity and WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531024/using-firebase-with-unity-and-webgl) and the solution: **Firebase simply is only compatible with Android and iOS - NOT with WebGL!** For WebGL you need to either implement a plug-in or search for alternatives

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'm new to stackoverflow and Unity, and this is my first project, so I'm sorry if this question is probably a duplicate. Do you know a fitting plug-in?
The "Using Firebase with Unity and WebGL" Question is outdated. With those answeres, I can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue is beacause you use the keyword **UnityEditor** in one your scripts but this script is not in **Editor** folder.
To fix this issue, do this :

1. Find all scripts containing “using UnityEditor”.
2. Move all these scripts to an **Editor folder**. Create this folder in Project if necessary.
   You can now generate your build.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue multiple times. In my case all the time I was importing "UnityEditor" in my game code. Try to search for "UnityEditor" in your game code and remove it.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was caused by a typo in non-editor code. Check for an `#if UNITY_EDITOR` or `#if !UNITY_EDITOR` block somewhere in your code that has a compiler error within it